# Open an Outlook oft template from SharePoint

Tags: vba, templates, sharepoint, outlook

I have an Outlook template file stored in SharePoint.

If I sync the file to my PC and use the local path the code works.

How do I, with a VBA macro in Outlook, open the file from SharePoint?

```vb
Sub AccessPass()

Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/Admin/Documents/AccessPass.oft")

msg.SentOnBehalfOfName = " xxx@xxx.com"

msg.Display

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the template on the local disk, the Outlook object model can deal with a local file path only, passing URL is not a supported scenario.

Comment: Thanks, that weird as the file opens in Outlook directly from SharePoint.

Comment: Programmatically you need to save the file locally and then use its local path for the `CreateItemFromTemplate` method. See https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/